# How to map a JSON string to Kotlin Map

Tags: json, kotlin

I have a simple Kotlin program that access a Mongo database and produce a JSON string as below;

```
"{
     "_id" : { "$oid" : "593440eb7fa580d99d1abe85"} , 
     "name" : "Firstname Secondname" ,
     "reg_number" : "ATC/DCM/1016/230" ,
     "oral" : 11 ,
     "oral_percent" : 73 , 
     "cat_1" : 57 , 
     "cat_2" : 60 , 
     "cat_average" : 59 , 
     "assignment" : 90
}"
```

How do I map this in Kotlin Map/MutableMap? Is there an API in Kotlin to read JSON and map it to Map/MutableMap?

Comment: Look at [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be done with [*Klaxon*](https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon). With this you can easily read the *Json* data as `JsonObject` which is actually a `MutableMap`.

```
val json: JsonObject = Parser().parse(jsonData) as JsonObject
```

Comment: Parser() is deprecated. the lib recommands to use Parser.default() instead

Answer (score 38):

No additional library is needed:

```
val jsonObj = JSONObject(jsonString)
val map = jsonObj.toMap()
```

where toMap is:

```
fun JSONObject.toMap(): Map<String, *> = keys().asSequence().associateWith {
    when (val value = this[it])
    {
        is JSONArray ->
        {
            val map = (0 until value.length()).associate { Pair(it.toString(), value[it]) }
            JSONObject(map).toMap().values.toList()
        }
        is JSONObject -> value.toMap()
        JSONObject.NULL -> null
        else            -> value
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems way more Kotlin'esque - upvoted. And the 'value.toMap()' recursive call was funny as hell. Also, that when-is conditional, never seen that before. Learning so much from one post, you deserve at least two upvotes for every single upvote.

Comment: Awesome answer. I would only replace the JSONArray part with `(0 until value.length()).map { value[it] }` - elegant and concise.

Comment: @RomanKotenko i couldn't because JSONObject takes only maps, not lists. I have to use .toMap recursively, in order to convert JSONObject.NULL to null

Comment: @muzzletov ahahaha thank you

Comment: sometimes import statements help. No clue where to get JSONObject from

Answer (score 9):

Using Jackson's [kotlin module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin), you can create a Map/MutableMap as below:

```
val jsonString = "{\n" +
            "  \"_id\": {\n" +
            "    \"\$oid\": \"593440eb7fa580d99d1abe85\"\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  \"name\": \"Firstname Secondname\",\n" +
            "  \"reg_number\": \"ATC/DCM/1016/230\",\n" +
            "  \"oral\": 11,\n" +
            "  \"oral_percent\": 73,\n" +
            "  \"cat_1\": 57,\n" +
            "  \"cat_2\": 60,\n" +
            "  \"cat_average\": 59,\n" +
            "  \"assignment\": 90\n" +
            "}"

val map = ObjectMapper().readValue<MutableMap<Any, Any>>(jsonString)
```

**Note:** In case you're getting the below compilation error

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied
```

Please ensure that you have added the the dependency of `jackson-module-kotlin` (for gradle: `compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:${jackson_version}"`) and have added the import for the **readValue** implementation as `import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue` in the place where you're using `readValue`

Comment: i get an error for "readValue" that says "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied."

Comment: @Raksha did that help?

Comment: ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, MutableMap::class.java)

Answer (score 5):

This can be done without any third party library:

```
@Throws(JSONException::class)
fun JSONObject.toMap(): Map<String, Any> {
    val map = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
    val keysItr: Iterator<String> = this.keys()
    while (keysItr.hasNext()) {
        val key = keysItr.next()
        var value: Any = this.get(key)
        when (value) {
            is JSONArray -> value = value.toList()
            is JSONObject -> value = value.toMap()
        }
        map[key] = value
    }
    return map
}

@Throws(JSONException::class)
fun JSONArray.toList(): List<Any> {
    val list = mutableListOf<Any>()
    for (i in 0 until this.length()) {
        var value: Any = this[i]
        when (value) {
            is JSONArray -> value = value.toList()
            is JSONObject -> value = value.toMap()
        }
        list.add(value)
    }
    return list
}
```

Usage to convert JSONObject to Map:

```
val jsonObject = JSONObject(jsonObjStr)
val map = jsonObject.toMap()
```

Usage to convert JSONArray to List:

```
val jsonArray = JSONArray(jsonArrStr)
val list = jsonArray.toList()
```

More info is [here](https://github.com/michaelavoyan/JSONExtentions/blob/main/JSONExtentions.kt)

Answer (score 5):

This is now also possible with `kotlinx.serialization`:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import kotlinx.serialization.json.jsonObject

val input = """{
     "_id" : { "some_id" : "593440eb7fa580d99d1abe85"} , 
     "name" : "Firstname Secondname" ,
     "reg_number" : "ATC/DCM/1016/230" ,
     "oral" : 11 ,
     "oral_percent" : 73 , 
     "cat_1" : 57 , 
     "cat_2" : 60 , 
     "cat_average" : 59 , 
     "assignment" : 90
}"""

val json = Json.parseToJsonElement(input)

val map = json.jsonObject.toMap()
```

Comment: it creates `Map<String, JsonElement>` but I need `Map<String, Any>`. How can I do so?

Comment: @philoopher97 you can cast the results with `as Map<String, Any>`, although that would be a mistake in most cases.

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to you, I solved it easily.
                 
However, you need to add the following in the build.gradle's dependencies.
               
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.0.1" // JVM dependency

Answer (score 4):

The latest version of the `org.json` library has `JSONObject.toMap()` so you can just do

```
val map = JSONObject(string).toMap()
```

So just add the `org.json:json:20220924` dependency to your project.

If you're writing for Android (and thus have an old version of the org.json library) then the following can be used.

```
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONObject

fun JSONObject.toMap(): Map<String, Any?> =
    keys().asSequence().associateWith { key -> toValue(get(key)) }

fun JSONArray.toList(): List<Any?> =
    (0 until length()).map { index -> toValue(get(index)) }

private fun toValue(element: Any) = when (element) {
    JSONObject.NULL -> null
    is JSONObject -> element.toMap()
    is JSONArray -> element.toList()
    else -> element
}
```