# Parse JSON without data class in Kotlin?

Tags: json, kotlin

There are many JSON parsers in Kotlin like Forge, Gson, JSON, Jackson... But they deserialize the JSON to a data class, meaning it's needed to define a data class with the properties corresponding to the JSON, and this for every JSON which has a different structure.

But what if you don't want to define a data class for every JSON you could have to parse?

I'd like to have a parser which wouldn't use data classes, for example it could be something like:

```
val jsonstring = '{"a": "b", "c": {"d: "e"}}'

parse(jsonstring).get("c").get("d") // -> "e"
```

Just something that doesn't require me to write a data class like

```
data class DataClass (
    val a: String,
    val b: AnotherDataClass
)

data class AnotherDataClass (
    val d: String
)
```

which is very heavy and not useful for my use case.

Does such a library exist? Thanks!

Comment: Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870961/how-to-map-a-json-string-to-kotlin-map). I believe it applies to your use case.

Comment: I guess you're refering to the answer with Klaxon. It seems to do exactly what I want, but Klaxon's Parser is deprecated.

Comment: in jackson you have `org.bson.Document` which acts like a sort of map. You can do `.get` and other things with it. I'm sure that all the others have similar objects.

Comment: Most, if not all, of the JSON parsers you list have generic ways to parse as well without the need to define the class

Answer (score 9):

With `kotlinx.serialization` you can [parse JSON String into a `JsonElement`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#parsing-to-json-element):

```
val json: Map<String, JsonElement> = Json.parseToJsonElement(jsonstring).jsonObject
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

```kotlin
val json = """{"a": "b", "c": {"d": "e"}}"""
val context = JsonPath.parse(json)
val str = context.read<String>("c.d")
println(str)
```

Output:

> Result: e