# Need help to convert fields of object into list in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin. Is there any where to conver fields of object into list? Need to iterate each of the fields and add it into a list

Example input = "conversion_rates":{
"USD":1,
"AED":3.6725,
"AFN":89.6333,
}

Expected output = [{"USD":1,}, { "AED":3.6725,}, {"AFN":89.6333,}]

Comment: Is this a kotlin map or a deserialized javascript object? If it is a kotlin map, you can access the entry set and turn it into a list. Here is a quick kotlin playground for if it is a kotlin map: https://pl.kotl.in/gkCESYZhw

Comment: If your object is JSON, then there your answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870961/how-to-map-a-json-string-to-kotlin-map, // continuing answer of @YogeshThambidurai